# Using python to clean up string encoding problems in text files

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, mojibake

I have a lot of XML documents and filenames for external files that have various forms of text corruption or Mojibake causing data quality problems during import. I've read a number of different posts on StackOverflow on correcting strings, but they fail to really outline how to cleanup text in a systematic way and python's `decode`, `encode` don't seem to be helping. How can I recover an XML file and filenames, using Python 2.7, containing characters in the range of Latin-1 (ISO-8859-1) but have mixed encodings generally?

Comment: This question is looking to combine what are pieces of the puzzle that can be gleaned from other more domain specific questions and add my personal experience to give a more canonical answer to the issue of how to cleanup text encoding issues.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### You have to make assumptions

If you can't make assumptions about the kinds of letters that you'll be encountering, you're probably in trouble. So it is good that in our document we can reasonably assume the Norwegian alphabet `A-Å`. There is no magic tool that will auto-correct every document that you encounter.

So within this domain we know that a file might contain `å` with a UTF-8 2-byte representation `0xc3 0xa5` or [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters), [Latin-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) and [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) will represent it as `0xe5`. Generally, this [character lookup](http://unicode-table.com/en/) is very nice and might make for a good bookmark if you find yourself researching a character.

#### Example

- The Norwegian `å`
- The corrupted version `Ã¥`

You can find a long list of these kinds of issues in this handy [debugging chart](http://i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html).

#### Basic Python encode, decode

This is the simplest way to hack the string back into shape if you know exactly what went wrong.

```
our_broken_string = 'Ã¥'
broken_unicode = our_broken_string.decode('UTF-8')
print broken_unicode # u'\xc3\xa5' yikes -> two different unicode characters
down_converted_string = broken_unicode.encode('LATIN-1')
print down_converted_string # '\xc3\xa5' those are the right bytes
correct_unicode = down_converted_string.decode('UTF-8')
print correct_unicode # u'\xe5' correct unicode value
```

#### Documents

When working with documents there are some relatively good assumptions that can be made. Words, whitespace and lines. Even if the document is XML, you can still think about it as words and not really worry too much about the tags or if the words are really words, you just need the smallest unit you can find. We can also assume that if the file has text encoding problems, it probably has line-ending issues as well depending on how many different OSes mangled that file. I would break on line endings, `rstrip`, and recombine the array using print to a `StringIO` file handle.

When preserving whitespace it might be tempting to run an XML document through a pretty-print function, but you shouldn't, we just want to correct the encoding of small text units without changing anything else. A good starting point is to see if you can get through the document line-by-line, word-by-word, NOT in arbitrary byte blocks and ignore the fact you're dealing with XML.

Here I leverage the fact that you'll get UnicodeDecodeErrors if the text is out of range for UTF-8 and then attempt LATIN-1. This worked in this document.

```
import unicodedata

encoding_priority = ['UTF-8', 'LATIN-1']
def clean_chunk(file_chunk):
    error_count = 0
    corrected_count = 0
    new_chunk = ''
    encoding = ''
    for encoding in encoding_priority:
        try:
            new_chunk = file_chunk.decode(encoding, errors='strict')
            corrected_count += 1
            break
        except UnicodeDecodeError, error:
            print('Input encoding %s failed -> %s' % (encoding, error))
            error_count += 1
    if encoding != '' and error_count > 0 and corrected_count > 0:
        print('Decoded. %s(%s) from hex(%s)' % (encoding, new_chunk, file_chunk.encode('HEX')))

    normalized = unicodedata.normalize('NFKC', new_chunk)

    return normalized, error_count, corrected_count


def clean_document(document):
    cleaned_text = StringIO()
    error_count = 0
    corrected_count = 0

    for line in document:
        normalized_words = []
        words = line.rstrip().split(' ')
        for word in words:
            normalized_word, error_count, corrected_count = clean_chunk(word)
            error_count += error_count
            corrected_count += corrected_count
            normalized_words.append(normalized_word)
        normalized_line = ' '.join(normalized_words)
        encoded_line = normalized_line.encode(output_encoding)
        print(encoded_line, file=cleaned_text)

    cleaned_document = cleaned_text.getvalue()
    cleaned_text.close()

    return cleaned_document, error_count, corrected_count
```

#### FTFY for dealing with Mojibake

If your problem is real [Mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake), like perhaps a bad filename. You can use [FTFY](http://ftfy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to try to heuristically correct your problem. Again, I'd take a word-by-word approach for best results.

```
import os
import sys
import ftfy
import unicodedata


if __name__ == '__main__':
    path = sys.argv[1]
    file_system_encoding = sys.getfilesystemencoding()
    unicode_path = path.decode(file_system_encoding)

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(unicode_path):
        for f in files:
            comparable_original_filename = unicodedata.normalize('NFC', f)
            comparable_new_filename = ftfy.fix_text(f, normalization='NFC')

            if comparable_original_filename != comparable_new_filename:
                original_path = os.path.join(root, f)
                new_path = os.path.join(root, comparable_new_filename)
                print "Renaming:" + original_path + " to:" + new_path
                os.rename(original_path, new_path)
```

This went through the directory correcting much uglier errors where the `å` had been mangled into `A\xcc\x83\xc2\xa5`. What is this? The capital letter `A` + `COMBINING LETTER TILDE` 0xcc 0x83 is one of several ways to represent `Ã` using [unicode equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence). This is really a job for FTFY, because it will actually perform a heuristic and puzzle out these kinds of issues.

#### Unicode normalization for comparison and filesystems

Another way would be to use the normalization of unicode to get the correct bytes.

```
import unicodedata

a_combining_tilde = 'A\xcc\x83'
# Assume: Expecting UTF-8 
unicode_version = a_combining_tilde.decode('UTF-8') # u'A\u0303' and this cannot be converted to LATIN-1 and get Ã
normalized = unicodedata.normalize('NFC', unicode_version) # u'\c3'
broken_but_better = normalized.encode('UTF-8') # '\xc3\x83` correct UTF-8 bytes for Ã.
```

So in summary, if you treated it as a UTF-8 encoded string `A\xcc\x83\xc2\xa5`, normalized it, and then down-converted to a LATIN-1 string and then back to UTF-8 you'd get the correct unicode back.

You need to be mindful of how the OS encodes filenames. You can retrieve that information with:

```
file_system_encoding = sys.getfilesystemencoding()
```

So let's say `file_system_encoding` is `UTF-8`, great right? Then you compare two seemingly identical unicode strings and they're not equal! FTFY, by default normalizes to `NFC`, HFS normalizes to an older version of `NFD`. So, simply knowing the encoding is the same isn't good enough, you'll have to normalize in the same way for comparisons to be valid.

- Windows NTFS stores unicode without normalization.
- Linux stores unicode without normalization.
- Mac HFS stores UTF-8 with a proprietary HFD normalization.

Node.js has a good guide about [dealing with different filesystems](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/working-with-different-filesystems/). In summary, normalize for comparison, don't arbitrarily renormalize filenames.

### Final notes

#### Lies, damned lies, and XML declarations

In XML documents you'll get something like this that is supposed to inform the XML parser about the text encoding.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
```

If you see this, it should be treated as a lie until proven to be true. You need to validate and handle the encoding issues before handing this document to an XML parser and you need to correct the declaration.

#### Lies, damned lies, and BOM markers

Byte-order markers sound like a great idea, but like their XML declaration cousin are totally unreliable indicators of a files encoding situation. [Within UTF-8, BOMs are NOT recommended](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8) and have no meaning meaning with respect to byte order. Their only value is to indicate that something is encoded in UTF-8. However, given the issues of text encoding the default is and should be to expect UTF-8.

Comment: In the paragraph "Lies, damned lies, and XML declarations", do you mean the encoding is *explicitly stated* to be ISO-8859-1 but this appears to be not true? (For example, it's mangled UTF-8.) Can it thus contain characters that are actually invalid for ISO-8859-1, i.e., from the range 0x7F-0x9F?

Comment: Yes. The header was likely machine generated and the content could be UTF-8, it could be LATIN-1, it could be mixed. So if handed a random XML document, you cannot trust the text encoding declaration unless you verify that it is all within range.

Comment: To take it further - you might trust that the XML generator produced a perfectly valid document, but someone else opened the document with a plain text editor and changed the encoding of all or part of the document to UTF-8 or CP-1252.